# How can I extract values from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, html, loops, foreach, rendering

I have the following array of objects where each object has a unique key-value pair

```
[
    {
        "nld": "Dutch",
        "pap": "Papiamento"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic",
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "por": "Portuguese",
        "tet": "Tetum"
    },
    {
        "deu": "German"
    },
    {
        "hun": "Hungarian"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "gil": "Gilbertese"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "mkd": "Macedonian"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "ber": "Berber",
        "mey": "Hassaniya",
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "mri": "Māori",
        "nzs": "New Zealand Sign Language"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "mya": "Burmese"
    },
    {
        "slv": "Slovene"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "niu": "Niuean"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "hin": "Hindi",
        "tam": "Tamil"
    },
    {
        "por": "Portuguese",
        "zho": "Chinese"
    },
    {
        "swe": "Swedish"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "ita": "Italian"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "fas": "Persian (Farsi)"
    },
    {
        "kir": "Kyrgyz",
        "rus": "Russian"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic",
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "sot": "Sotho"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic",
        "fra": "French",
        "zdj": "Comorian"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "zho": "Chinese"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "dan": "Danish",
        "fao": "Faroese"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "aym": "Aymara",
        "grn": "Guaraní",
        "que": "Quechua",
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "cnr": "Montenegrin"
    },
    {
        "ita": "Italian"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "swa": "Swahili"
    },
    {
        "por": "Portuguese",
        "pov": "Upper Guinea Creole"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic",
        "eng": "English",
        "tir": "Tigrinya"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "msa": "Malay"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "kal": "Greenlandic"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "fin": "Finnish",
        "swe": "Swedish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "rar": "Cook Islands Māori"
    },
    {
        "nor": "Norwegian"
    },
    {
        "ind": "Indonesian"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "fra": "French",
        "kin": "Kinyarwanda"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "nld": "Dutch",
        "pap": "Papiamento"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French",
        "por": "Portuguese",
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French",
        "gsw": "Swiss German",
        "ita": "Italian",
        "roh": "Romansh"
    },
    {
        "khm": "Khmer"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "srp": "Serbian"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "crs": "Seychellois Creole",
        "eng": "English",
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French",
        "hat": "Haitian Creole"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic",
        "arc": "Aramaic",
        "ckb": "Sorani"
    },
    {
        "div": "Maldivian"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic",
        "som": "Somali"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "afr": "Afrikaans",
        "eng": "English",
        "nbl": "Southern Ndebele",
        "nso": "Northern Sotho",
        "sot": "Southern Sotho",
        "ssw": "Swazi",
        "tsn": "Tswana",
        "tso": "Tsonga",
        "ven": "Venda",
        "xho": "Xhosa",
        "zul": "Zulu"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "sin": "Sinhala",
        "tam": "Tamil"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "por": "Portuguese"
    },
    {
        "isl": "Icelandic"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "nld": "Dutch",
        "pap": "Papiamento"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "mlt": "Maltese"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "tha": "Thai"
    },
    {
        "aym": "Aymara",
        "que": "Quechua",
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "dan": "Danish"
    },
    {
        "rus": "Russian",
        "uzb": "Uzbek"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "glv": "Manx"
    },
    null,
    {
        "jpn": "Japanese"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "deu": "German",
        "fra": "French",
        "nld": "Dutch"
    },
    {
        "ben": "Bengali"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "ton": "Tongan"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French",
        "run": "Kirundi"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "smo": "Samoan"
    },
    {
        "kor": "Korean"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "deu": "German",
        "fra": "French",
        "ltz": "Luxembourgish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "smo": "Samoan",
        "tkl": "Tokelauan"
    },
    {
        "nep": "Nepali"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "tsn": "Tswana"
    },
    {
        "est": "Estonian"
    },
    {
        "kaz": "Kazakh",
        "rus": "Russian"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "nld": "Dutch"
    },
    {
        "ces": "Czech",
        "slk": "Slovak"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "por": "Portuguese"
    },
    {
        "hye": "Armenian"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French",
        "kon": "Kikongo",
        "lin": "Lingala",
        "lua": "Tshiluba",
        "swa": "Swahili"
    },
    {
        "ukr": "Ukrainian"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "zho": "Chinese"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "pih": "Norfuk"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "fil": "Filipino"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "por": "Portuguese"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "swe": "Swedish"
    },
    {
        "vie": "Vietnamese"
    },
    {
        "grn": "Guaraní",
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "bjz": "Belizean Creole",
        "eng": "English",
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "gle": "Irish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "fra": "French",
        "mfe": "Mauritian Creole"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "pau": "Palauan"
    },
    {
        "mon": "Mongolian"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "ell": "Greek",
        "tur": "Turkish"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "hrv": "Croatian"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "msa": "Malay"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "bel": "Belarusian",
        "rus": "Russian"
    },
    {
        "por": "Portuguese"
    },
    {
        "amh": "Amharic"
    },
    {
        "cha": "Chamorro",
        "eng": "English",
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "rus": "Russian",
        "tgk": "Tajik"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic",
        "ber": "Berber"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "lav": "Latvian"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "swa": "Swahili"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "fra": "French",
        "nld": "Dutch"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "cat": "Catalan"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "jam": "Jamaican Patois"
    },
    {
        "afr": "Afrikaans",
        "deu": "German",
        "eng": "English",
        "her": "Herero",
        "hgm": "Khoekhoe",
        "kwn": "Kwangali",
        "loz": "Lozi",
        "ndo": "Ndonga",
        "tsn": "Tswana"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "mah": "Marshallese"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "cal": "Carolinian",
        "cha": "Chamorro",
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French",
        "kon": "Kikongo",
        "lin": "Lingala"
    },
    {
        "slk": "Slovak"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "deu": "German"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "tvl": "Tuvaluan"
    },
    {
        "kor": "Korean"
    },
    {
        "rus": "Russian",
        "tuk": "Turkmen"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "aze": "Azerbaijani",
        "rus": "Russian"
    },
    {
        "lit": "Lithuanian"
    },
    {
        "sqi": "Albanian"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "smo": "Samoan"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French",
        "sag": "Sango"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "zho": "Chinese"
    },
    {
        "kat": "Georgian"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "pol": "Polish"
    },
    {
        "bar": "Austro-Bavarian German"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "prs": "Dari",
        "pus": "Pashto",
        "tuk": "Turkmen"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "tur": "Turkish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "ron": "Romanian"
    },
    {
        "sqi": "Albanian",
        "srp": "Serbian"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic",
        "heb": "Hebrew"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic",
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "urd": "Urdu"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "nor": "Norwegian"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "ssw": "Swazi"
    },
    {
        "dzo": "Dzongkha"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "fra": "French",
        "nfr": "Guernésiais"
    },
    {
        "nld": "Dutch"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "ron": "Moldavian"
    },
    {
        "bwg": "Chibarwe",
        "eng": "English",
        "kck": "Kalanga",
        "khi": "Khoisan",
        "ndc": "Ndau",
        "nde": "Northern Ndebele",
        "nya": "Chewa",
        "sna": "Shona",
        "sot": "Sotho",
        "toi": "Tonga",
        "tsn": "Tswana",
        "tso": "Tsonga",
        "ven": "Venda",
        "xho": "Xhosa",
        "zib": "Zimbabwean Sign Language"
    },
    {
        "por": "Portuguese"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "nya": "Chewa"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "zho": "Chinese",
        "eng": "English",
        "msa": "Malay",
        "tam": "Tamil"
    },
    {
        "bis": "Bislama",
        "eng": "English",
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "bul": "Bulgarian"
    },
    {
        "ell": "Greek"
    },
    {
        "nno": "Norwegian Nynorsk",
        "nob": "Norwegian Bokmål",
        "smi": "Sami"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "swa": "Swahili"
    },
    {
        "rus": "Russian"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French",
        "mlg": "Malagasy"
    },
    {
        "grn": "Guaraní",
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "fij": "Fijian",
        "hif": "Fiji Hindi"
    },
    {
        "bos": "Bosnian",
        "hrv": "Croatian",
        "srp": "Serbian"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "fra": "French",
        "nrf": "Jèrriais"
    },
    {
        "por": "Portuguese"
    },
    {
        "ita": "Italian",
        "lat": "Latin"
    },
    {
        "lao": "Lao"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic",
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "hmo": "Hiri Motu",
        "tpi": "Tok Pisin"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "nau": "Nauru"
    }
]
```

and I would like to loop through this array of objects (using Javascript) and extract each value so I can render it into an html list like the example below. Im not sure exactly how to do this and any help would be appreciated.

```
<li>Dutch</li>
<li>Papiamento</li>
<li>Arabic</li>
<li>French</li>
<li>Portuguese</li>
<li>Tetum</li>
<li>German</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a list of unique values:

You can use a combination of `for` and `for-in` and add to an object checking if it has the property value in it and if so continue else add it to the new object of unique values using `hasOwnProperty`, then iterate the keys of the object holding the unique values to form your list:

```js
const myobj = [
    {
        "nld": "Dutch",
        "pap": "Papiamento"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic",
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "por": "Portuguese",
        "tet": "Tetum"
    },
    {
        "deu": "German"
    },
    {
        "hun": "Hungarian"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "gil": "Gilbertese"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "mkd": "Macedonian"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "ber": "Berber",
        "mey": "Hassaniya",
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "mri": "Māori",
        "nzs": "New Zealand Sign Language"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "mya": "Burmese"
    },
    {
        "slv": "Slovene"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "niu": "Niuean"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "hin": "Hindi",
        "tam": "Tamil"
    },
    {
        "por": "Portuguese",
        "zho": "Chinese"
    },
    {
        "swe": "Swedish"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "ita": "Italian"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "fas": "Persian (Farsi)"
    },
    {
        "kir": "Kyrgyz",
        "rus": "Russian"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic",
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "sot": "Sotho"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic",
        "fra": "French",
        "zdj": "Comorian"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "zho": "Chinese"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "dan": "Danish",
        "fao": "Faroese"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "aym": "Aymara",
        "grn": "Guaraní",
        "que": "Quechua",
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "cnr": "Montenegrin"
    },
    {
        "ita": "Italian"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "swa": "Swahili"
    },
    {
        "por": "Portuguese",
        "pov": "Upper Guinea Creole"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic",
        "eng": "English",
        "tir": "Tigrinya"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "msa": "Malay"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "kal": "Greenlandic"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "fin": "Finnish",
        "swe": "Swedish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "rar": "Cook Islands Māori"
    },
    {
        "nor": "Norwegian"
    },
    {
        "ind": "Indonesian"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "fra": "French",
        "kin": "Kinyarwanda"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "nld": "Dutch",
        "pap": "Papiamento"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French",
        "por": "Portuguese",
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French",
        "gsw": "Swiss German",
        "ita": "Italian",
        "roh": "Romansh"
    },
    {
        "khm": "Khmer"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "srp": "Serbian"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "crs": "Seychellois Creole",
        "eng": "English",
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French",
        "hat": "Haitian Creole"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic",
        "arc": "Aramaic",
        "ckb": "Sorani"
    },
    {
        "div": "Maldivian"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic",
        "som": "Somali"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "afr": "Afrikaans",
        "eng": "English",
        "nbl": "Southern Ndebele",
        "nso": "Northern Sotho",
        "sot": "Southern Sotho",
        "ssw": "Swazi",
        "tsn": "Tswana",
        "tso": "Tsonga",
        "ven": "Venda",
        "xho": "Xhosa",
        "zul": "Zulu"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "sin": "Sinhala",
        "tam": "Tamil"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "por": "Portuguese"
    },
    {
        "isl": "Icelandic"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "nld": "Dutch",
        "pap": "Papiamento"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "mlt": "Maltese"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "tha": "Thai"
    },
    {
        "aym": "Aymara",
        "que": "Quechua",
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "dan": "Danish"
    },
    {
        "rus": "Russian",
        "uzb": "Uzbek"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "glv": "Manx"
    },
    null,
    {
        "jpn": "Japanese"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "deu": "German",
        "fra": "French",
        "nld": "Dutch"
    },
    {
        "ben": "Bengali"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "ton": "Tongan"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French",
        "run": "Kirundi"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "smo": "Samoan"
    },
    {
        "kor": "Korean"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "deu": "German",
        "fra": "French",
        "ltz": "Luxembourgish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "smo": "Samoan",
        "tkl": "Tokelauan"
    },
    {
        "nep": "Nepali"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "tsn": "Tswana"
    },
    {
        "est": "Estonian"
    },
    {
        "kaz": "Kazakh",
        "rus": "Russian"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "nld": "Dutch"
    },
    {
        "ces": "Czech",
        "slk": "Slovak"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "por": "Portuguese"
    },
    {
        "hye": "Armenian"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French",
        "kon": "Kikongo",
        "lin": "Lingala",
        "lua": "Tshiluba",
        "swa": "Swahili"
    },
    {
        "ukr": "Ukrainian"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "zho": "Chinese"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "pih": "Norfuk"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "fil": "Filipino"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "por": "Portuguese"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "swe": "Swedish"
    },
    {
        "vie": "Vietnamese"
    },
    {
        "grn": "Guaraní",
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "bjz": "Belizean Creole",
        "eng": "English",
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "gle": "Irish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "fra": "French",
        "mfe": "Mauritian Creole"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "pau": "Palauan"
    },
    {
        "mon": "Mongolian"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "ell": "Greek",
        "tur": "Turkish"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "hrv": "Croatian"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "msa": "Malay"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "bel": "Belarusian",
        "rus": "Russian"
    },
    {
        "por": "Portuguese"
    },
    {
        "amh": "Amharic"
    },
    {
        "cha": "Chamorro",
        "eng": "English",
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "rus": "Russian",
        "tgk": "Tajik"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic",
        "ber": "Berber"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "lav": "Latvian"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "swa": "Swahili"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "fra": "French",
        "nld": "Dutch"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "cat": "Catalan"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "jam": "Jamaican Patois"
    },
    {
        "afr": "Afrikaans",
        "deu": "German",
        "eng": "English",
        "her": "Herero",
        "hgm": "Khoekhoe",
        "kwn": "Kwangali",
        "loz": "Lozi",
        "ndo": "Ndonga",
        "tsn": "Tswana"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "mah": "Marshallese"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "cal": "Carolinian",
        "cha": "Chamorro",
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French",
        "kon": "Kikongo",
        "lin": "Lingala"
    },
    {
        "slk": "Slovak"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "deu": "German"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "tvl": "Tuvaluan"
    },
    {
        "kor": "Korean"
    },
    {
        "rus": "Russian",
        "tuk": "Turkmen"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "aze": "Azerbaijani",
        "rus": "Russian"
    },
    {
        "lit": "Lithuanian"
    },
    {
        "sqi": "Albanian"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "smo": "Samoan"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French",
        "sag": "Sango"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "zho": "Chinese"
    },
    {
        "kat": "Georgian"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "pol": "Polish"
    },
    {
        "bar": "Austro-Bavarian German"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "prs": "Dari",
        "pus": "Pashto",
        "tuk": "Turkmen"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "tur": "Turkish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "ron": "Romanian"
    },
    {
        "sqi": "Albanian",
        "srp": "Serbian"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic",
        "heb": "Hebrew"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic",
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "urd": "Urdu"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "nor": "Norwegian"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "ssw": "Swazi"
    },
    {
        "dzo": "Dzongkha"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "fra": "French",
        "nfr": "Guernésiais"
    },
    {
        "nld": "Dutch"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "ron": "Moldavian"
    },
    {
        "bwg": "Chibarwe",
        "eng": "English",
        "kck": "Kalanga",
        "khi": "Khoisan",
        "ndc": "Ndau",
        "nde": "Northern Ndebele",
        "nya": "Chewa",
        "sna": "Shona",
        "sot": "Sotho",
        "toi": "Tonga",
        "tsn": "Tswana",
        "tso": "Tsonga",
        "ven": "Venda",
        "xho": "Xhosa",
        "zib": "Zimbabwean Sign Language"
    },
    {
        "por": "Portuguese"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "nya": "Chewa"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "zho": "Chinese",
        "eng": "English",
        "msa": "Malay",
        "tam": "Tamil"
    },
    {
        "bis": "Bislama",
        "eng": "English",
        "fra": "French"
    },
    {
        "bul": "Bulgarian"
    },
    {
        "ell": "Greek"
    },
    {
        "nno": "Norwegian Nynorsk",
        "nob": "Norwegian Bokmål",
        "smi": "Sami"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "swa": "Swahili"
    },
    {
        "rus": "Russian"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French",
        "mlg": "Malagasy"
    },
    {
        "grn": "Guaraní",
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "fij": "Fijian",
        "hif": "Fiji Hindi"
    },
    {
        "bos": "Bosnian",
        "hrv": "Croatian",
        "srp": "Serbian"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "fra": "French",
        "nrf": "Jèrriais"
    },
    {
        "por": "Portuguese"
    },
    {
        "ita": "Italian",
        "lat": "Latin"
    },
    {
        "lao": "Lao"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "ara": "Arabic",
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "hmo": "Hiri Motu",
        "tpi": "Tok Pisin"
    },
    {
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English",
        "nau": "Nauru"
    }
];

//declare an object to hold unique values
let myvals = {};

//benchmark the performance
const start = performance.now();

for(let a = 0; a < myobj.length; a++){
  for(let val in myobj[a]){
    if(!myvals.hasOwnProperty(myobj[a][val])){
       myvals[myobj[a][val]] = null;
    }
  }
}

let list = "";
for(let v in myvals){
  list += "<li>" + v + "</li>";
}
console.log(list);
console.log(performance.now() - start + " milliseconds");
```

Answer (score 0):

## Changing the data structure

We can get an array of only the names of the languages, if we don't need the abbreviations, we can simply apply a reduce method over the languages array:

```
const languages = [
    {
        "nld": "Dutch",
        "pap": "Papiamento"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French",
        "gsw": "Swiss German",
        "ita": "Italian",
        "roh": "Romansh"
    },
    {
        "khm": "Khmer"
    },
    {
        "eng": "English"
    },
    {
        "fra": "French"
    },
    // ...
]

const result = languages.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  return [ ...acc, ...Object.values(cur) ]
}, [])

console.log(result) // [ 'Dutch', 'Papiamento', 'French', 'Swiss German', 'Italian', 'Romansh', 'Khmer', 'English', 'French' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this and debug item object to find your code.

```
const items = JSON.parse('Your Json');

foreach(var item in items){
    var li_element = document.createElement("li"); 
    li_element.innerHTML = item;
    document.body.appendChild(li_element);
    //or
    var ul_ol_element document.getElementbyID("your ul or ol object id");
    ul_ol_element.appendChild(li_element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

List this?

```js
const arr = [
    { "nld": "Dutch"      , "pap": "Papiamento" , },
    { "ara": "Arabic"     , "fra": "French"     , },
    { "por": "Portuguese" , "tet": "Tetum"      , },
    { "deu": "German"     ,                     , },
    { "hun": "Hungarian"  ,                     , },
    { "eng": "English"    , "gil": "Gilbertese" , },
    // . . .
];

const languages = arr.flatMap( obj => Object.values(obj) );
```

If you need that list to be the set of unique languages, just pour it into a `Set`, thus:

```
const uniqueLanguages = [ ... new Set(languages) ];
```

And to sort the resulting list...

```
const uniqueLanguages = [ ... new Set(languages) ].sort();
```

Answer (score 0):

With this line, you can remove NULL values and create a list of unique languages

```
let fData = [...new Set(data.filter(d => !!d).flatMap(Object.values))]
```

- `[...new Set(` takes the result and strips out any dupes
- `.filter(d=>!!d)` keeps only non-null values
- `flatMap(` lets us map the multi-length objects into a flat array
- `flatMap(Object.values)` lets us just get the language names

Then to turn it into LI tags, you can do something like this

```
document.querySelector('#list').innerHTML = fData.map(d => `<li>${d}</li>`).join('');
```

```js
let data = [{
    "nld": "Dutch",
    "pap": "Papiamento"
  },
  {
    "ara": "Arabic",
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "por": "Portuguese",
    "tet": "Tetum"
  },
  {
    "deu": "German"
  },
  {
    "hun": "Hungarian"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "gil": "Gilbertese"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "mkd": "Macedonian"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "ber": "Berber",
    "mey": "Hassaniya",
    "spa": "Spanish"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "mri": "Māori",
    "nzs": "New Zealand Sign Language"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "spa": "Spanish"
  },
  {
    "mya": "Burmese"
  },
  {
    "slv": "Slovene"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "niu": "Niuean"
  },
  {
    "ara": "Arabic"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "ara": "Arabic"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "hin": "Hindi",
    "tam": "Tamil"
  },
  {
    "por": "Portuguese",
    "zho": "Chinese"
  },
  {
    "swe": "Swedish"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "ita": "Italian"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "fas": "Persian (Farsi)"
  },
  {
    "kir": "Kyrgyz",
    "rus": "Russian"
  },
  {
    "ara": "Arabic",
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "sot": "Sotho"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "ara": "Arabic",
    "fra": "French",
    "zdj": "Comorian"
  },
  {
    "spa": "Spanish"
  },
  {
    "zho": "Chinese"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "dan": "Danish",
    "fao": "Faroese"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "aym": "Aymara",
    "grn": "Guaraní",
    "que": "Quechua",
    "spa": "Spanish"
  },
  {
    "cnr": "Montenegrin"
  },
  {
    "ita": "Italian"
  },
  {
    "spa": "Spanish"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "swa": "Swahili"
  },
  {
    "por": "Portuguese",
    "pov": "Upper Guinea Creole"
  },
  {
    "ara": "Arabic",
    "eng": "English",
    "tir": "Tigrinya"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "msa": "Malay"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "kal": "Greenlandic"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "fin": "Finnish",
    "swe": "Swedish"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "rar": "Cook Islands Māori"
  },
  {
    "nor": "Norwegian"
  },
  {
    "ind": "Indonesian"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "fra": "French",
    "kin": "Kinyarwanda"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "nld": "Dutch",
    "pap": "Papiamento"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French",
    "por": "Portuguese",
    "spa": "Spanish"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French",
    "gsw": "Swiss German",
    "ita": "Italian",
    "roh": "Romansh"
  },
  {
    "khm": "Khmer"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "srp": "Serbian"
  },
  {
    "spa": "Spanish"
  },
  {
    "crs": "Seychellois Creole",
    "eng": "English",
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "ara": "Arabic"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French",
    "hat": "Haitian Creole"
  },
  {
    "ara": "Arabic",
    "arc": "Aramaic",
    "ckb": "Sorani"
  },
  {
    "div": "Maldivian"
  },
  {
    "ara": "Arabic",
    "som": "Somali"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "afr": "Afrikaans",
    "eng": "English",
    "nbl": "Southern Ndebele",
    "nso": "Northern Sotho",
    "sot": "Southern Sotho",
    "ssw": "Swazi",
    "tsn": "Tswana",
    "tso": "Tsonga",
    "ven": "Venda",
    "xho": "Xhosa",
    "zul": "Zulu"
  },
  {
    "ara": "Arabic"
  },
  {
    "sin": "Sinhala",
    "tam": "Tamil"
  },
  {
    "ara": "Arabic"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "por": "Portuguese"
  },
  {
    "isl": "Icelandic"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "nld": "Dutch",
    "pap": "Papiamento"
  },
  {
    "spa": "Spanish"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "mlt": "Maltese"
  },
  {
    "spa": "Spanish"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "tha": "Thai"
  },
  {
    "aym": "Aymara",
    "que": "Quechua",
    "spa": "Spanish"
  },
  {
    "dan": "Danish"
  },
  {
    "rus": "Russian",
    "uzb": "Uzbek"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "glv": "Manx"
  },
  null,
  {
    "jpn": "Japanese"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "deu": "German",
    "fra": "French",
    "nld": "Dutch"
  },
  {
    "ben": "Bengali"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "ton": "Tongan"
  },
  {
    "ara": "Arabic"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French",
    "run": "Kirundi"
  },
  {
    "ara": "Arabic"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "smo": "Samoan"
  },
  {
    "kor": "Korean"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "deu": "German",
    "fra": "French",
    "ltz": "Luxembourgish"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "smo": "Samoan",
    "tkl": "Tokelauan"
  },
  {
    "nep": "Nepali"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "tsn": "Tswana"
  },
  {
    "est": "Estonian"
  },
  {
    "kaz": "Kazakh",
    "rus": "Russian"
  },
  {
    "ara": "Arabic"
  },
  {
    "nld": "Dutch"
  },
  {
    "ces": "Czech",
    "slk": "Slovak"
  },
  {
    "spa": "Spanish"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "por": "Portuguese"
  },
  {
    "hye": "Armenian"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French",
    "kon": "Kikongo",
    "lin": "Lingala",
    "lua": "Tshiluba",
    "swa": "Swahili"
  },
  {
    "ukr": "Ukrainian"
  },
  {
    "spa": "Spanish"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "zho": "Chinese"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "pih": "Norfuk"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "fil": "Filipino"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "por": "Portuguese"
  },
  {
    "spa": "Spanish"
  },
  {
    "swe": "Swedish"
  },
  {
    "vie": "Vietnamese"
  },
  {
    "grn": "Guaraní",
    "spa": "Spanish"
  },
  {
    "bjz": "Belizean Creole",
    "eng": "English",
    "spa": "Spanish"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "gle": "Irish"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "fra": "French",
    "mfe": "Mauritian Creole"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "pau": "Palauan"
  },
  {
    "mon": "Mongolian"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "ara": "Arabic"
  },
  {
    "ell": "Greek",
    "tur": "Turkish"
  },
  {
    "spa": "Spanish"
  },
  {
    "hrv": "Croatian"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "msa": "Malay"
  },
  {
    "ara": "Arabic"
  },
  {
    "bel": "Belarusian",
    "rus": "Russian"
  },
  {
    "por": "Portuguese"
  },
  {
    "amh": "Amharic"
  },
  {
    "cha": "Chamorro",
    "eng": "English",
    "spa": "Spanish"
  },
  {
    "rus": "Russian",
    "tgk": "Tajik"
  },
  {
    "ara": "Arabic",
    "ber": "Berber"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "lav": "Latvian"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "swa": "Swahili"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "fra": "French",
    "nld": "Dutch"
  },
  {
    "spa": "Spanish"
  },
  {
    "cat": "Catalan"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "jam": "Jamaican Patois"
  },
  {
    "afr": "Afrikaans",
    "deu": "German",
    "eng": "English",
    "her": "Herero",
    "hgm": "Khoekhoe",
    "kwn": "Kwangali",
    "loz": "Lozi",
    "ndo": "Ndonga",
    "tsn": "Tswana"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "mah": "Marshallese"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "cal": "Carolinian",
    "cha": "Chamorro",
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French",
    "kon": "Kikongo",
    "lin": "Lingala"
  },
  {
    "slk": "Slovak"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "deu": "German"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "tvl": "Tuvaluan"
  },
  {
    "kor": "Korean"
  },
  {
    "rus": "Russian",
    "tuk": "Turkmen"
  },
  {
    "ara": "Arabic"
  },
  {
    "spa": "Spanish"
  },
  {
    "aze": "Azerbaijani",
    "rus": "Russian"
  },
  {
    "lit": "Lithuanian"
  },
  {
    "sqi": "Albanian"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "smo": "Samoan"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French",
    "sag": "Sango"
  },
  {
    "spa": "Spanish"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "zho": "Chinese"
  },
  {
    "kat": "Georgian"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "pol": "Polish"
  },
  {
    "bar": "Austro-Bavarian German"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "prs": "Dari",
    "pus": "Pashto",
    "tuk": "Turkmen"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "tur": "Turkish"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "ron": "Romanian"
  },
  {
    "sqi": "Albanian",
    "srp": "Serbian"
  },
  {
    "ara": "Arabic",
    "heb": "Hebrew"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "ara": "Arabic"
  },
  {
    "ara": "Arabic",
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "urd": "Urdu"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "nor": "Norwegian"
  },
  {
    "spa": "Spanish"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "ssw": "Swazi"
  },
  {
    "dzo": "Dzongkha"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "fra": "French",
    "nfr": "Guernésiais"
  },
  {
    "nld": "Dutch"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "ron": "Moldavian"
  },
  {
    "bwg": "Chibarwe",
    "eng": "English",
    "kck": "Kalanga",
    "khi": "Khoisan",
    "ndc": "Ndau",
    "nde": "Northern Ndebele",
    "nya": "Chewa",
    "sna": "Shona",
    "sot": "Sotho",
    "toi": "Tonga",
    "tsn": "Tswana",
    "tso": "Tsonga",
    "ven": "Venda",
    "xho": "Xhosa",
    "zib": "Zimbabwean Sign Language"
  },
  {
    "por": "Portuguese"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "nya": "Chewa"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "ara": "Arabic"
  },
  {
    "ara": "Arabic"
  },
  {
    "zho": "Chinese",
    "eng": "English",
    "msa": "Malay",
    "tam": "Tamil"
  },
  {
    "bis": "Bislama",
    "eng": "English",
    "fra": "French"
  },
  {
    "bul": "Bulgarian"
  },
  {
    "ell": "Greek"
  },
  {
    "nno": "Norwegian Nynorsk",
    "nob": "Norwegian Bokmål",
    "smi": "Sami"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "swa": "Swahili"
  },
  {
    "rus": "Russian"
  },
  {
    "fra": "French",
    "mlg": "Malagasy"
  },
  {
    "grn": "Guaraní",
    "spa": "Spanish"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "fij": "Fijian",
    "hif": "Fiji Hindi"
  },
  {
    "bos": "Bosnian",
    "hrv": "Croatian",
    "srp": "Serbian"
  },
  {
    "spa": "Spanish"
  },
  {
    "ara": "Arabic"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "fra": "French",
    "nrf": "Jèrriais"
  },
  {
    "por": "Portuguese"
  },
  {
    "ita": "Italian",
    "lat": "Latin"
  },
  {
    "lao": "Lao"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "ara": "Arabic",
    "eng": "English"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "hmo": "Hiri Motu",
    "tpi": "Tok Pisin"
  },
  {
    "spa": "Spanish"
  },
  {
    "eng": "English",
    "nau": "Nauru"
  }
];
let fData = [...new Set(data.filter(d => !!d).flatMap(Object.values))]
document.querySelector('#list').innerHTML = fData.map(d => `<li>${d}</li>`).join('');
```

```html
<ul id='list'></ul>
```